# typescript does not find jszip types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, jszip

I have a strange issue where typescript does not find the types for `jszip`.

- other types work fine
- the types seem to be in the correct location

in my source-file I use these **imports** e.g.

```
import * as fast_csv from 'fast-csv';
import { Response } from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';
```

all work fine, except for `jszip`: 
[image: es]

```
Error:(9, 24) TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'jszip'. 'ROOT/node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

When I look into my (one and only) **`node_modules/@types`** dir, all files are there:
[image]

here are the relevant entries from **`package.json`**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/joi": "^15.0.1",
    "fast-csv": "^2.5.0",
    "jszip": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/hapi__joi": "^15.0.1",
    "@types/jszip": "^3.1.6",
   }
```

notes:

- I thought typescript only uses the name: e.g. when importing `jszip` it should search for `@types/jszip`

  - but it seems that I am wrong, because the types of `@hapi/joi` are called `@types/hapi__joi` and they work fine
- I think also the version mismatch shoudl not be an issue: `"jszip": "^3.2.1"` vs. `"@types/jszip": "^3.1.6"`, right?
- the code-completion in the IDE shows also the types: 
  [image]

Any idea, what I am missing?

related links:

- [typescript doc: consume declaration files](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html)
- [@types, typeRoots and types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)
- [npm @types/jszip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jszip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 04.2020**

It seems that the issue is fixed in jszip `3.3.0`: see [Fix browser module resolution #614](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/pull/614)

Moreover I think the issue was only related to the client side (angular) build. Since node has its own [stream package](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/stream.html)

**Original**

I found the issue: in `tsconfig.json` we had an explicit path definition:

```
"paths": {
  "jszip": ["node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"],
```

after removing this, the build failed with:

```
ERROR in C:/devroot/node_modules/jszip/lib/readable-stream-browser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\devroot\node_modules\jszip\lib'
```

and the solution to this is to install the `stream` package (thanks to this [issue-comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10625#issuecomment-390878516))

```
npm i stream
```

or when using [typedi](https://github.com/typestack/typedi):

```
typedi stream
```

and now the build works fine.

Note: maybe there is a better way to fix this - see this [issue-comment](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/issues/776#issuecomment-502966523)